# How to add partman partitioning recipe file into 'd-i environment' for Ubuntu preseed

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, preseed

The [Ubuntu docs on preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apbs04.html#preseed-partman) specify that a separate partitioning recipe can be passed as a value for a preseed file:

```
# Or provide a recipe of your own...
# If you have a way to get a recipe file into the d-i environment, you can
# just point at it.
#d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe_file string /hd-media/recipe
```

I've gotten a custom partitioning scheme to work using the 'in-line' configuration method where the entire recipe is a single backslash-escaped line. However, I cannot seem to get the installer to find the `recipe` file when it is kept as a separate file. Booting from the ISO errors out with:

> Failed to partition the selected disk

What do the Ubuntu docs mean by **get a recipe file into the d-i environment** ? How specifically do I do that?

Is this the environment of the installer or the target? Is `/hd-media/` in the above example assumed to exist on the ISO or somewhere else? If not, where specifically do I place a recipe file so that the installer can find it, rather than in-lining the entire thing?

---

More background: I'm creating a 'remastered' ISO by:

- Downloading a stock Ubuntu ISO
- Mounting it readonly
- Copying the mountpoint to a temporary dest
- Modifying files such as isolinux/txt.cfg in the temporary dest
- Repackaging it with `mkisofs`

I have a custom `.seed` file at `/preseed/ubuntu-custom.seed` that contains

```
d-i     partman-auto/method                         string  lvm
d-i     partman/default_filesystem                  string  ext4
d-i     partman-auto/choose_recipe                  select  boot-root
d-i     partman-auto/expert_recipe                  string  /hd-media/recipe
```

and also execute:

```
cp -LTf "${DIR}/ubuntu-server-unattended.seed" preseed/ubuntu-server-unattended.seed
if [[ ! -d hd-media ]]; then
    mkdir hd-media
fi
cp -LTf "${DIR}/recipe" hd-media/recipe
```

My guess is this is wrong because it ends up on the target, not the 'd-i installer environment', whatever exactly that means.

E.g. copying the templated files from source control into the temporary directory used to house the new ISO contents.

I know that the issue is *not* with the recipe itself, since it works perfectly well in the 'oneline version' e.g.

```
d-i     partman-auto/expert_recipe                  string  \
    boot-root ::                                            \
        500 1000 1000 ext2                                  \
            $primary{ }                                     \
            $bootable{ }                                    \
            method{ format }                                \
            format{ }                                       \
            use_filesystem{ }                               \
            filesystem{ ext2 }                              \
            label{ boot }                                   \
            mountpoint{ /boot }                             \
        .                                                   \
        4000 8000 8000 $default_filesystem                  \
            $lvmok{ }                                       \
            lv_name{ RootVol }                              \
            method{ format }                                \
            format{ }                                       \
            use_filesystem{ }                               \
            mountpoint{ / }                                 \
            $default_filesystem{ }                          \
            options/defaults{ defaults }                    \
            options/discard{ discard }                      \
            options/iversion{ iversion }                    \
        .                                                   \
```

(The above is an abridged version.)

In the separate-recipe-file process, I simply transfer this to `recipe` and axe the back-slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recipe file should be in the installer environment, **not** in the target.  To add a file to the installer environment I will sometimes use a preseed file that includes lines like the following

```
d-i partman/early_command string \
  wget -O /run/my_recipe http://someserver/path/to/recipe ;

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe_file string /run/my_recipe
```

If you are adding your recipe file to a custom ISO and booting from that then I would expect the files on the ISO to be accessible in the installer environment with a base path of `/cdrom`.  I'm basing that on [this section of the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apbs02.html) that show examples of accessing files on different installation media.

```
- if you're booting a remastered CD or image:
  preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed.cfg
...
- if you're installing from USB media (put the preconfiguration file in the
  toplevel directory of the USB stick):
  preseed/file=/hd-media/preseed.cfg
```

The installer environment can also be inspected directly with the VT2.  Use `Alt-F2` if you have console access to open it, and `Alt-F1` to return to the main installer UI.  This is useful for working through issues like finding a file's path.

Please be aware there are different Ubuntu installers.  Based on your progress it sounds like you are using one that supports preseed.

- Ubuntu Desktop Installer (`ubiquity`) supports preseed but with some customization
- Ubuntu Live Server Installer (`subiquity`) does **not** use preseed and starting with `20.04` provides its own `autoinstall` feature
- Ubuntu Legacy Server Installer (`debian-installer`/`d-i`) supports preseed but will not be created for releases after `20.04`